# F# precise calculating with decimals?

Tags: math, f#

I'm trying to do a precise calculation with floats like

```
let pi = double (22/7)

printfn "%f" (cos(2.00*pi*1.00/2.00))
// output: -0.989992
```

On a calculator I get -1, so it can round up and down correctly, however, when I do this in F# I get the result/output: -0.989992 which is close to -1, but how do I get an output -1 so it rounds up and down correctly?

I tried to read about the topic and it seems like I need to import a module, can this be true?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your calculation is off not because of rounding error, but because 22/7 is a *very* loose approximation of the value of π.

- 22/7 = 3.142857142857...
- π = 3.14159265358979...
- 22/7 - π = 0.00126448927...

Wolfram Alpha uses a much better approximation of π than 22/7, so that's why your calculation is showing different results from Wolfram Alpha.

Instead of doing `let pi = double (22/7)`, you should just use `System.Math.PI` (e.g., `let pi = System.Math.PI`). That will get you an *accurate* value for `(cos(2.00*pi*1.00/2.00))`. No need for rounding.

See [the docs for `Math.PI`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.pi?view=netframework-4.7.2) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

So the question has a few problems.

1. As others point out 22/7 is just an approximation of PI
2. Aslo, `let pi = double(22/7)` results in `pi = 3.0`. This because 22/7 is integer division in F#.
3. When comparing with wolfram the expression uses a better approximation of PI than 3.0 meaning the F# result differs from wolfram rather significantly

When asking Wolfram and F# to compute the same expression: `cos(3)` the result is as following.

F#: `cos 3.0` => `-0.989992496600445`
Wolfram: `cos(3)` => `-0.98999249660044545727157279473126130239367909661558832881`

Wolfram do compute more decimals but we see that the numbers only differs by `> 1e-15`

When we ask F# and Wolfram to what cos(pi) is they are in agreement:

F#: `cos System.Math.PI` => `-1.0`
Wolfram: `cos(pi)` => `-1`

Answer (score -1):

I found the way, sorry! You need to use System.Math.Round. No need to import anything as its already built-in.

I.e.: System.Math.Round(System.Math.Round(cos((2.00*pi*2.00/ 2.00)), 0))

Comment: Actually the main problem is that `22/7` is equal to `3` which is not a good approximation of PI.